# Characters in structures

Tags: c++, c, struct

A quick question : What is the meaning of **char c:4** in the structure given below

```
struct s 
 { 
 char c:4;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for "Bit fields"

Comment: If he doesn't know what it is, how would he google for bit fields? Would it not be more beneficial to give a short explanation with links for follow-up?

Comment: He just told him the keyword to search for.

Comment: @jrok It just seems a bit dismissive of his question, that's all I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [*bit field*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) consisting of a four-bit portion of a `char`. You can define more bit fields to subdivide a larger type into "nibblets", like this:

```
struct s 
 { 
 char c:4;
 char d:2;
 char e:2;
 };
```

This `struct` defines three fields, all "packed" into a single `char`. The `c` field can hold sixteen distinct values; fields `d` and `e` can hold four values each.

Answer (score 1):

The `char c:4` means that it is a `char` sized variable of which 4 bits are the variable `c`. Put another way, `c` does not refer to the entire 8 bit `char` memory space, only four bits of it. This is a mechanism for bit-packing flags and uncommon data sizes into a structure.

Answer (score 1):

Bit-fields are a quirky feature of the C language whose exact specifications and behavior have been somewhat inconsistent over the years; later versions of the C standard have nailed down some aspects of the behavior enough to prevent compilers from doing some useful things, but not enough to make them portable in any useful fashion.

If two or more consecutive members of a structure have the same underlying integer type, and have their field name followed by a colon and a number, the compiler will attempt to pack each one after the first into the same storage element as the one before.  If it cannot do so, it will advance to the next storage element.

Thus, on a machine where `unsigned short` is sixteen bits, a declaration:

```
struct {
  unsigned short a1 : 5;
  unsigned short a2 : 5;
  unsigned short a3 : 7;
  unsigned short a4 : 5;
  unsigned short a5 : 4;
  unsigned short a6 : 6;
}
```

the compiler will pack a1 and a2 into a 16-bit integer; since a3 won't fit in the same integer as a1 and a2 (the total would be 17 bits), it will start a new one.  Although a4 would bit with a1 and a2, the fact that a3 is in the way means that it will be put with a3.  Then a5 will be placed with a3 and a4, filling up the second spot.  A6 will be given a 16-bit spot all its own.

Note that if the underlying type of all those structure elements had been a 32-bit `unsigned int`, everything could have been packed into one such item rather than three 16-bit ones.

Frankly, I really dislike the rules around bitfields.  They rules are sufficiently vague that the underlying representation one compiler generates for bitfield data may not be readable by another, but they're sufficiently specific that compilers are forbidden from generating what could otherwise be useful data structures (e.g. it should be possible to pack four six-bit numbers into a 3-byte (24-bit) structure, but unless a compiler happens to have a 24-bit integer type there is way to request that).  Still, the rules are what they are.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write a resourceful comment where you shared your experience with bit-fields. Cheers